# Copy a XSSF/HSSF-Cells into a new XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

## My problem

I need to **exactly** copy cells from `XSSFWorkbook`s and `HSSFWorkbook`s to a new `XSSFWorkbook`. So my cells can be of both types: `XSSFCell` and `HSSFCell`.

By **exactly**, I mean that I also need to copy the `CellStyle` including the `CellBorder` and `CellFill` properties as well as the `DefaultRowHeight` and `DefaultColumnWidth` of the workbook itself. Also the height and width for each row and column should be copied.
(Copying `CellStyle` sometimes results in strange behaviour like I already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941691/copying-of-xlsx-files-with-poi-apache-results-in-strange-behaviour)).

## My question

What's the best way to do this? I don't want to copy each property manually by myself. Especially if I don't know if my input cells are of type `XSSFCell` or `HSSFCell`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## My solution

I've solved my problem through downscaling of the requirements. Now I only concentrate on `XSSFWorkbook`s.

Exactly copying a `XSSFWorkbook` is really easy. To copy a `XSSFCellStyle` to another workbook just use the following code:

```
// Copy cell style from `sourceCell` to `targetCell`
XSSFCellStyle sourceCellStyle = sourceCell.getCellStyle();
XSSFCellStyle clonedCellStyle = newWorkbook.createCellStyle();
clonedCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(sourceCellStyle);
targetCell.setCellStyle(clonedCellStyle);
```

It's important that the target workbook has the same style source as the source workbook. Otherwise the cloned cell style will look differently.

```
final StylesTable sourceStylesSource = sourceWorkbook.getStylesSource();
final StylesTable tagetStylesSource = targetWorkbook.getStylesSource();

sourceStylesSource.getFonts().forEach(font -> targetStylesSource.putFont(font, true));
sourceStylesSource.getFills().forEach(fill -> targetStylesSource.putFill(new XSSFCellFill(fill.getCTFill())));
sourceStylesSource.getBorders().forEach(border -> targetStylesSource.putBorder(new XSSFCellBorder(border.getCTBorder())));
```

I hope this helps someone!
Regards, winklerrr

---

## PS

If someone can't downscale the requirements, then maybe it's helpful to split up the task into two smaller tasks:

1. Convert a `HSSFWorkbook` to a `XSSFWorkbook` and vice versa.
2. Copy a `XSSFWorkbook` exactly.

Comment: If you fancy turning this into a stand-alone example [to go in the Apache POI examples section](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf), pop it in [an enhancement bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=POI) or a [GitHub pull request](https://github.com/apache/poi) and we'd love to add it in!